# How to create DB in SQL Express using SQL commands?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am reading a book on SQL and it gives me scripts to run to create a database. But I have only SQL Express 10, which doesn't look like has tools to run SQL commands. Is there any way to run the scripts?

Comment: There is SQL Management Studio Express : http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?familyid=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en

Comment: Also SQLCMD - a command line tool : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702.aspx][http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702.aspx]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K, I'm going to provide the answer for this even though it was in the comments above so it can be closed (not sure if there's a way to close an unanswered question):

> There is SQL Management Studio Express http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?familyid=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en – THEn
>
> Also SQLCMD - a command line tool : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702.aspx – Dave Cluderay

Comment: the link is actually for Studio Express 2005, which won't work with Express 2008. Make sure you donwload the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Download [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=08E52AC2-1D62-45F6-9A4A-4B76A8564A2B&displaylang=en), it has the tools to run queries and scripts.

Make sure you download the 2008 one for SQL Express 10 (the one in my link), the 2005 will not connect to your SQL Express.